# How to add a URL parameter using a WSO2 Mediation Flow?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have successfully deployed a WSO2 API Manager. I am already using mediation flows for setting Header information, but now I am adding an API that requires a key to be set as an URL parameter. However I would like this to be added in the background so that the end-users don't have to worry about this key.

How can this be done in a Message Mediation Policy/Flow? Obviously the other parameters that are already present should stay untouched.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you can access the **key** inside the synapse context. Then you can assign the key value to the uri.var object as below.

```
<property name="uri.var.key" expression="get-property('userParames.key')"/>
```

Now you can simply construct the endpoint as,

```
<endpoint>
   <http uri-template="https://{uri.var.hostname}:{uri.var.portnum}/abc/{uri.var.key}"/>
</endpoint>
```

Comment: But how can I make sure that the existing URL parameters don't get affected?

Comment: Since we are adding new variable as **key** to the url.var object the existing URL parameters won't be affected. You can verify it by testing.